# How to instruct OS X to wait for an application to close before interrupting a shutdown?

Tags: macos, shutdown

I'm using several virtual machines that take time to be paused when I want to reboot the system. It prevents OS X Lion from shutting down properly, because the VMware process is still running seconds after the reboot has been initiated. How can I tell OS X Lion to disable this shutdown interruption and simply wait for the process to be terminated? I know that I could manually pause the VMs before doing the reboot, but I really do want to change this behavior instead of using this kind of workaround.

Comment: I've given you my thoughts.  One approach that comes to mind (other than the obvious manual approach) is that there could be command-line tools for vmware that include shutdown commands.  Maybe it would catch to those.

Comment: I think what you really want here is to extend the timeout OSX has between the shutdown being requested, and it killing the shutdown because the apps haven't finished closing.

Comment: Alternately, you could write your own shutdown script that first requested vmware to close, then triggered an OSX shutdown.

Comment: Extending this timeout could help a lot. Now I'm facing this with VMware Fusion but it could be another app with heavy closing operations too. On Windows, there's a "WaitToKillServiceTimeout" registry tweak to avoid this problem, how about OS X?

Comment: It actually sounds to me like Lion is intentionally not killing applications during shutdown.  Maybe it has something to do with versions and resume.

Comment: If VMWare doesn't play well with this procedure, you might end up needing an unbearably long shutdown timeout.  If it were me, I'd just pause the VMs manually to be certain.